# How correctly declare variables in SQL update request with Dapper when it isn't an object?

Tags: c#, sql-update, dapper, execute

I would like to do this request :

```
public int UpdateOneColumn(string dbName, string tableName, string columnName, string newValue, string whereColumnName, string whereColumnNameValue)
{
    string sql = @"update @tableName set @columnName = @newValue where @whereColumnName = @whereColumnNameValue";

    return connection.Execute(sql, new {tableName, columnName, newValue, whereColumnName, whereColumnNameValue });    
}
```

but I get an error

> tableName must be declared

Does someone know how to correctly declare my variables "tableName, columnName, newValue, whereColumnName and whereColumnNameValue" ?

Is this function correct? (I'm not sure I can do `update @tableName` and `where @whereColumnName`)

Comment: Are you sur? I can not find any syntax of Dapper in

Comment: you can't have `@tablename`, `@columnName` etc as parameters to a sql statement - build the sql statement before calling dapper

Comment: Be careful how you interpret that. Do build the column and tables names into your update statement. Do **NOT** build the data values into your update statement. Those should still be parameter variables. And hopefully, those column and table names are determined by your software such that you're **NOT** just letting the user type in their own names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int UpdateOneColumn(string dbName, string tableName, string setColumn, object setValue, string whereColumn, object whereValue)
{
    string sql = $"UPDATE {tableName} SET {setColumn} = @s WHERE {whereColumn} = @w";
    return connection.Execute(sql, new { s = setValue, w = whereValue });    
}
```